# Reservations SQL query

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

I'm creating a reservation booking system and I'm trying to write a query which shows which resources are free at a given time (allows users to choose which stations to book)

I have two tables in my database

**First table**

```
|workstationid | location|
+--------------+---------+
|     1        |Downsview|
|     2        |Downsview|
|     3        |Downsview|
|     4        |Downsview|
|     5        |Downsview|
```

**Second table**

```
|wsid |location    |email       |duration |startDate |endDate |
+-----+------------+------------+---------+----------+--------+
|  1  | Downsview  | randomemail|    5    | 9/4/2017 |9/8/2017|
```

The query I am executing is

```
SELECT r.wsid,r.location FROM test_revision2 r WHERE r.location='Downsview' AND not exists(select 1 from test_bookings2 b WHERE r.wsid = b.wsid AND r.location = b.location AND b.startDate > '9/5/2017'AND b.endDate <'9/5/2017')
```

However the problem in the query is that it is returning all of 5 locations as available however as you can see in my second table there is a booking from Sept4th-Sept 8 for workstation 1.

```
 workstationid   location
       1          Downsview
       2          Downsview
       3          Downsview
       4          Downsview
       5          Downsview
```

Comment: PSA: [ISO date format](https://xkcd.com/1179/).

Comment: What is expected result for date `9/5/2017`? workstationids 2,3,4,5 ?

Comment: Yes that is correct @OtoShavadze

Answer (score 2):

Probably you need something like this:

```
    select * from first_table
    where
    not exists (
        select 1 from Second_table
        where 
        startDate <= '9/5/2017' and endDate >= '9/5/2017'
        and
        wsid = first_table.workstationid
    )
```

Note, that if you need check between two dates instead of just one , then you can check date overlaps like this:

```
...
where 
startDate <= 'higher_date_here' and endDate >= 'lower_date_here'
```

Comment: This is the correct answer what I was looking for that led to my final solution was that the higher date is the start date

Comment: quick question @OtoShavadze when I execute the query select * from test_revision2 where test_revision2.location ='Downsview' AND not exists(select 1 from test_bookings2 where startDate <'11/1/2017' and endDate >'10/31/2017' and test_bookings2.wsid = test_revision2.wsid),, the output I get is 2,3,4,5, however it should be (1..5) because there is no booking on that date in my db it's really buggy

Comment: @rahulchawla - Are you sure you don't have booking location on that time interval? I just checked here: http://rextester.com/LXI74274 and it works fine, gives all 5 rows from first_table

Comment: Yes I am sure the last row in my table is `10/9/2017-10/13/2017 and it gives me 2,3,4,5

Comment: Do you have to cast to a date? my dates are varchars in my database however it works for some scenarios @OtoShavadze

Answer (score 1):

First, your tables repeat data?  Do you need the first table?

Secondly, from just using your second table, test_bookings2

```
SELECT 
    r.wsid
    , r.location
FROM test_bookings2 r
WHERE NOT (Startdate <= '2017-09-05' AND EndDate >= '2017-09-05')
```

In other words, what you're trying to do is return all the rows that are not active for your given dates.  To check actives at any point in a date range, you need to say:

```
WHERE StartDate <= @EndDate AND EndDate >= @StartDate
```

That will return all the bookings that are live at any point in your date range.

```
WHERE NOT(StartDate <= @EndDate AND EndDate >= @StartDate)
```

NOT reverses the result so when it returns true, instead its a false.

This should then give you all the rows that are not active in your date range.

Comment: Why are you not using the first table? what if there are no bookings for a certain workstationID in the bookings2 table.. this query isn't working for me

Comment: the first table holds a foreign key connection to the second, the first table manages the workstation id and their location

Comment: First table holds existing workstations and their location - the second table only hold bookings(like a booking history)

Comment: Sorry, your table structures confused me because of the repetition of WSID and location. Try this `SELECT r.wsid,r.location FROM test_revision2 r WHERE r.location='Downsview' AND not exists(select 1 from test_bookings2 b WHERE r.wsid = b.wsid AND r.location = b.location AND b.startDate <= '9/5/2017'AND b.endDate >='9/5/2017')`

Comment: Nope, if you switch the signs so that `StartDate <=` and `EndDate >=` that should give you all the test_bookings that were active on the date/range that you specified.

Comment: I booked workstation #2 for 9/25/2017 and I made the range

Comment: 9/05/2017-9/30/2017 so therefore 3,4,5 should show However only 2,3,4,5 is showing

Comment: See what I mean?

Comment: run this `SELECT CAST('5/9/2017' AS DATE)` and check that it returns the date you expect.  I made a set of structures representative of your supplied tables and this works.  Check that the date in your database, returns what you think it should.

Comment: Or try this: `SELECT r.wsid,r.location FROM test_revision2 r WHERE r.location='Downsview' AND not exists(select 1 from test_bookings2 b WHERE r.wsid = b.wsid AND r.location = b.location AND b.startDate <= '2017-05-09' AND b.endDate >='2017-05-09')`

Comment: Hmm, looking at your previous post, are you sure the date columns in your table are actually dates and not VARCHARs?

Comment: I just checked this and yes they are varchars in the table, would this make a difference? I parsed them correctly I think @preql - I mean it works for some instances but not all test cases

Answer (score 0):

Problem and solution was that date was varchar in my database and I had to use a cast on my query